# Play framework file upload and CSRF still not working

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to make the play file upload sample work: https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-fileupload-example/tree/2.6.x

But I get the error messages as soon as I press the "upload file" button:
[warn] p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because no or invalid token found in body for /upload
[warn] p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed with NoTokenInBody for /upload

and the browser tells me: "Unauthorized
You must be authenticated to access this page."

I've read this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/lH5AOS2szU8

So the problem should be fixed and the test passes so I'm stuck.
Help?

Answer (score 0):

I made Simple Project that may help you fix this problem.

```
scalaVersion = "2.12.6"
playVersion = "2.6.19"
```

Visit: https://github.com/rexardiente/Scala-Play-Traning

Comment: This will simply fix the problem..

`@helper.form(action = CSRF(routes.HomeController.upload), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
      <input type="file" name="picture">
      <input type="submit" id="upload" value="upload file"/>
    }`

Comment: Thanks. It works. I had to change it slightly because of compilation errors such as `form` being defined twice.
It looks like this:

````
@import helper.CSRF

@main("Welcome to Play") {
  @helper.form(action = CSRF(routes.HomeController.upload), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
    @helper.inputFile(form("name"))
    <input type="submit" id="upload" value="upload file"/>
  }
}
````

Comment: Welcome, I'm happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It works. Thanks.
I just had an error saying that `form` is defined twice so I changed the import to:

```
@import helper.CSRF
```

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the file size limit in `application.conf` worked for me:

```
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=1024k
```

Change 1024k to your preferred size limit.